# hasAuthority method for only POST and PUT httpmethods

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

Here is my configure code snippet

```
@Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.
        authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/user/**").hasAnyAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/api/status/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN").anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .exceptionHandling()
        .accessDeniedHandler(new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler());
        }
```

In this I need to make `ROLE_ADMIN` to access only `POST` and `PUT` httpmethods. He should not be able to access `GET` or `DELETE` httpmethod. I need this to be done in a single `.antMatchers()` method.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at this Spring [example project](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/rest/security#writing-a-security-policy). You can define matchers per path **and** HTTP verb.

> ```java
> http
>     .authorizeRequests()
>         .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/employees").hasRole("ADMIN")
>         .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/employees/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
>         .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PATCH, "/employees/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
> ```